# Как сделать так, чтобы ViewContreoller был виден поверх предыдущего? Наподобие UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

Что то похожее на это
[image: Screen]
либо на UIAlertController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы хотите `UIViewController`, Вам необходим modal переход over current context.

Пример одного из вариантов, на [GitHub](https://github.com/VAndrJ/ExampleModalControllerForSO) с демонстрацией работы.